# unable to read the file from postman

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman

I was trying postman with a Java clientava client. I was getting the following output

```
com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RealResponseBody@c9673cf
```

the original output is

```
Curl -I "http://ec2-52-34-14-38.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/ec2-user/prediction_output/part-00000?user.name=ec2-user&op=OPEN"

1234.566788
```

here is my java code.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import java.io.IOException;
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getMsg() throws IOException {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
.url("http://ec2-52-34-14-38.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/ec2-user/prediction_output/part-00000?user.name=ec2-user&op=OPEN")
 .build();
 com.squareup.okhttp.Response responses = null;
 responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
 System.out.println(responses);
 return Response.status(200).entity(responses.body().toString()).build();
}
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`response.body().string()`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/ResponseBody.java#L82) not `toString()`.
- Use the above also in `System.out.println`.
- Your method `getMsg()` says `@Produces("application/json")` but your built response is `text/plain`.

Comment: I also tried this one.but still it shows same message only.